# flutter videoplayer widget , video zoom to fill width of player while not in fullscreen

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-video-player

i have a flutter widget that shows a video , i want it to act like twitter app video player . what i mean is for example the video has aspect ratio of 9:16 (so its a vertical video) i want the widget to zoom to center of the video just to Fill all the available Width of the video player(yes crop i don't care), but when i get to Fullscreen mode the video shall fill the screen while maintaining it's whole content (not cropped)

btw, also if the video has a different aspect ratio like a horizontal one it shows correctly with my current code.
i am working with flutterflow but i can code it in native flutter too.
here is my code custom widget
`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class Videoplayer extends StatefulWidget {
  const Videoplayer({
    Key? key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    this.videopath,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final String? videopath;

  @override
  _VideoplayerState createState() => _VideoplayerState();
}

class _VideoplayerState extends State<Videoplayer> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  bool _isFullScreen = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset(widget.videopath!)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {
          // Ensure that the video starts playing when it's initialized
          _controller.play();
        });
      });

    // Enable video controls
    _controller.setVolume(1.0); // Set volume to maximum
    _controller.setLooping(true); // Enable looping
    _controller.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0); // Set playback speed to normal
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  void _toggleFullScreen() {
    setState(() {
      _isFullScreen = !_isFullScreen;
    });

    if (_isFullScreen) {
      _controller.pause(); // Pause video when entering fullscreen
    } else {
      _controller.play(); // Resume video when exiting fullscreen
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: _toggleFullScreen,
      child: _isFullScreen
          ? AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
            )
          : _buildVideoPreview(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildVideoPreview() {
    return Center(
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            VideoPlayer(_controller),
            VideoPlayerControls(controller: _controller),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class VideoPlayerControls extends StatefulWidget {
  final VideoPlayerController controller;

  const VideoPlayerControls({Key? key, required this.controller})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoPlayerControlsState createState() => _VideoPlayerControlsState();
}

class _VideoPlayerControlsState extends State<VideoPlayerControls> {
  late bool _isPlaying;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isPlaying = widget.controller.value.isPlaying;
    widget.controller.addListener(_listener);
  }

  void _listener() {
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _isPlaying = widget.controller.value.isPlaying;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          reverseDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          child: _isPlaying
              ? SizedBox.shrink()
              : Container(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                  child: Center(
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: Colors.white),
                      onPressed: () {
                        widget.controller.play();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              if (_isPlaying) {
                widget.controller.pause();
              } else {
                widget.controller.play();
              }
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.controller.removeListener(_listener);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: if you think i need to change the package i can , can you recommend a different package ?

Comment: please can anyone help me or point me to the right direction ???